# Prove that $(|u-s|+|x-y|)^2\leq 2|u-s|^2+2|x-y|^2$.

Tags: analysis, self-learning

Prove that $(|u-s|+|x-y|)^2\leq 2|x-y|^2+2|u-s|^2$.

My professor used this inequality for a proof last week. How would one prove this? I thought about using the Cauchy-Swartz inequality.

This is not a homework question. I am interested in the proof just for self-learning.

Comment: Call it $(a+b)^2 \leqslant 2a^2 + 2b^2$ for better reading. Expand the left hand side, cancel common terms, get $2ab \leqslant a^2 + b^2$. Subtract $2ab$ from both sides, $0\leqslant (a-b)^2$.

Comment: Hint: $|a||b| \leq |a|^2 + |b|^2$.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(a+b)^2\le (a+b)^2+(a-b)^2 = (a^2+2ab+b^2)+(a^2-2ab+b^2)= 2a^2+2b^2.$$